# What is the difference between % and , in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using a `String` in Python and need to update it

```
line = ''
byte_data = 0
```

What is the difference between these two syntaxes (what they do):

```
line += "%c" % byte_data

line += "%c", byte_data
```

Comment: When you ran this, what differences did you see?  Please include the output in your question.  Also, did you try using `print` to see what the differences are?  Finally, what did you read in the Python language manual?  Can you please include a quote or a link to the pages you read?  It helps if you include the research you did, and the **specific** things you found that confused you.

Comment: Always inlcude this: What are you trying to do, why are you trying to do it, and in which way did it not succeed?

Answer (score 5):

The former [adds `\x00`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) to the string, and the latter [results in a `TypeError`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that one works and one does not.

```
>>> line = ''
>>> byte_data = 0
>>> line += "%c" % byte_data
>>> line
'\x00'
>>> line += "%c", byte_data

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    line += "%c", byte_data
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects
>>>
```

I'm not quite sure where you've seen comma used to populate strings, but unfortunately that will result in a TypeError.